# scrolling a div in a bootstrap 4 layout with body 100vh

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Given this layout:

```
<div class="fill-page">
  <div class="row">
    <item class="item col"></item>
    <item class="item col"></item>
    <item class="item col"></item>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="scroll">
      <table class="status">
      ...
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have set the `div.fill-page` to take up the height of the container using

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.fill-page {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 100%;  
}
```

This contains the 2 rows.
I am attempting to ensure that `div.scroll` is set to scroll it's content with

```
div.scroll {
      overflow: scroll;
      height: 100%;
}
```

The second row is overflowing the content, and not containing it within the `body` at 100vh.

*How do I ensure that the second row takes up as much remaining space as possible, and allowing the `div.scroll` to scroll the contents internally?*

**[I have a bootply to demonstrate.](https://www.bootply.com/vhhqJ4TW3R)**
The example shows the green bordered body at 100vh, and the second row overflowing the div instead of scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox (built into Bootstrap 4) on the `fill-page` container.

https://www.bootply.com/vhhqJ4TW3R (updated)

```
<div class="fill-page d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row flex-shrink">
    <item class="item col"></item>
    <item class="item col"></item>
    <item class="item col"></item>
  </div>
  <div class="row flex-grow">
    <div class="scroll col-1">
        <table class="status">
            ..
        </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additionally, use another class to make bottom row to grow(fill height) like this:

```
.flex-grow {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

As a side note, the Bootstrap `.row` is only meant to contain `.col-` so you should give the scroll columns a defined `.col-*` width. Otherwise there's no reason to use a `.row` there.